# Npgsql.PostgresException: '42703: column "p_i_procedure_id" does not exist

Tags: asp.net, postgresql, npgsql

I am beginner in Postgres and I am trying to execute a query in Postgres via npgsql library in .NET Core 6.

Here is the query:

```
public static string Qry =>
    @"SELECT DISTINCT *
    FROM crosstab( 'select prc.""Title"" as ""JobProcedure"", c.""Name"" as ""CategoryName"", COUNT(j.""JobID"") as ""Count""
    from ""Job"" as j
    inner join  ""JobProcedure"" as jp on j.""JobID"" = jp.""JobID""
    inner join ""JobPositions"" as jp2 on jp.""JobID"" = jp2.""JobID""
    inner join ""Category"" as c on c.""CategoryID"" = jp2.""CategoryID""
    inner join ""Procedure"" as prc on prc.""ProcedureID"" = jp.""ProcedureID""
    where jp.""ProcedureID"" = p_i_procedure_id AND (j.""PublishedDate"" between p_i_date_1 and p_i_date_2) and
    j.""IsActive"" = TRUE
    AND j.""Publish"" = TRUE
    AND jp.""IsActive"" = TRUE
    GROUP BY c.""Name"" ,prc.""Title""')
    AS final_result(""JobProcedure"" VARCHAR(250), ""IV-b"" BIGINT, ""IV-a"" BIGINT, ""III-b"" BIGINT, ""III-a"" BIGINT, ""II-b"" BIGINT,  ""II-a"" BIGINT)"
```

The error message is: `Npgsql.PostgresException: '42703: column "p_i_procedure_id" does not exist'`
p_i_procedure_id, p_i_date_1 and p_i_date_2 are parameters of the query

Where is the problem ?

Comment: Do you have a variable named _p_i_procedure_id_? Are you trying to pass its value in the WHERE statement to check against the _jp.""ProcedureID""_ field values?

Comment: @Steve I am trying to pass value to these parameters inside where statement

Comment: _p_i_procedure_id_ doesn't seem to be a parameter but the name of a variable embedded inside a string. A parameter placeholder inside a sql command text is usually prefixed with some special character. In oracle and npgsql is the : character. Can you show the code where you execute this procedure? Did you add the parameter to the command executed?

Comment: For using parameters, see https://www.npgsql.org/doc/basic-usage.html#parameters. The recommended parameter placeholders are $1, $2 (that's the native PG placeholder format), although Npgsql can also detect @p or :p and rewrite these for you.